# What is the meaning of selection probability in genetic algorithm with roullete selection method

Tags: genetic-algorithms

I am studying an article about implementation of genetic algorithm. Here is the parameters which are used in this article:

[image]

As I know, in roullete selection method, probability of selecting individuals is based on their cost function values. the more optimum individual has the higher probability of being selected. So, what is the meaning of selection probability here?

**UPDATE**

Here is the link to the article:

[Thinned Concentric Circular Array Antennas Synthesis Using Genetic Algorithm](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/6148734)

Comment: Please, provide the source of the table to better assess the answer.

Comment: Hello @noe , I've placed the link to the article.